# zsh completion: offer completions for files and --options in any order

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have sample command `foo`, which takes one or more file names, plus any combination of 3 --options. Moreover, the options can be specified anywhere on the commandline, before, after or between the filenames.

```
foo --bbb file.txt --aaa file2.txt --ccc
```

I have this completion file where I specify the potions:

```
#compdef foo

 local -a args

 args+=(
    '--aaa'
    '--bbb'
    '--ccc'
 )
```

what do I have to add to the end, so that local files are completed with my --options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`compadd`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd) builtin as many times as you want to declare more completions. Typically this happens via one of the many [helper functions of the “new” completion system](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System).

The simplest thing you can do is to call both `compadd` and `_files`.

```
#compdef foo
local -a args
args=(--aaa --bbb --ccc)
compadd -- $args
_files
```

Instead of calling `compadd` directly, you should call a helper function such as [`_describe`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fdescribe) which allows the completions to be configured according to the context and to have descriptions.

```
#compdef foo
local args
args=('--aaa:Enable aye' '--bbb:Enable bee' '--ccc:Enable sea')
_describe -o 'Options' args
_files
```

The [`_arguments`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fregex_005farguments) function generally makes it easier to specify completions for a command, although in your simple case there's not much to gain from it. Do use it if your command supports `--` to indicate that everything after `--` is a file name and not an option even if it starts with a dash — that's what `_arguments`'s `-S` option does. The `*` before options indicates that the option may appear multiple times; without it, the option will not be offered again if it's already present.

```
#compdef foo
_arguments -S \
    '*--aaa[Enable aye]' \
    '*--bbb[Enable bee]' \
    '*--ccc[Enable sea]' \
    '*:file:_files'
```

If your command supports `--help` to print help in a format that is close enough to the de facto standard established by GNU, you can tell `_arguments` to parse the output of `--help`, and then you only need to specify finer behavior that can't be deduced from the `--help` output.

```
#compdef foo
_arguments --
```

If you don't need anything beyond what can be deduced from the `--help` output, you don't need to define a completion function: just declare [`_gnu_generic`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fgnu_005fgeneric) as the completion function for your command.

```
compdef _gnu_generic foo
```